# Image inside TouchableOpacity not showing

Tags: image, react-native, touchableopacity

I'm currently trying to set up an image inside TouchableOpacity. It isn't showing and I'm stuck on why that is. Please let me know if you can help. TIA!

I've basically copied this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity from the official docs, but to no avail.

Thought maybe my TouchableOpacity element wasn't full screen but that's not the case (when I set the background color, I see it fill the screen).

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onWaitingButtonPress.bind(this)}>
    <Image style={styles.imagestyle} source={{uri: "https://www.dollargeneral.com/media/catalog/product/cache/image/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/0/0/00870101.jpg"}}/>
</TouchableOpacity>

const styles = {
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "stretch",
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  imageStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "contain"
  }
};
```

I get the red background to fill the whole screen, but the image does not.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more what is not working, image is not showing or the click event is not working?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response. The image is not showing, but the click event is working.

Answer (score 1):

flex: 1 cover the entire width and height of its container. probably your view's dimensions are 0.

if your touchable is showing, try this;

```
imageStyle: {
   width: "100%",
   height: "100%"
}
```

if it's not;

```
button: {
   width: 100,
   height: 100
}
```

or,

```
button: {
   width: "100%,
   height: "100%"
}
```

so, you can understand the difference between them when trying these

Comment: Hi, thanks Orhan for your response. None of the solutions you've provided seem to work. Also, changing the button size doesn't seem to affect image either. The button size does change, but that just makes the clickable element (i.e., TouchableOpacity) smaller, with the image still being as sneaky as usual.

Comment: I tried your code  on the https://snack.expo.io/ and it works perfectly. Did you try this on android or ios? Maybe you need to try to reset caches with npm start -- --reset-cache. As I said your code is working fine on my side and also what I wrote as an example works too.

Comment: interesting.. I'll reset-cache and get back to you. Thanks so much! Also, I'm working in ios and only tried it through the simulator.

Comment: So, I got it to work in a roundabout weird way. I've used the <ImageBackground> Element instead of the <Image> Element and somehow the image started showing... baffled and trying to understand why but no complaints from me. I'll read up on it more and try to make it work with <Image>. Thanks!

Comment: ui elements can be confused sometimes. glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Flex:1 in parent covers entire area but flex1 in image cover only height of entire screen. Here width becomes 0 since flex direction is column by default. Try setting some width lfor image ike "100%' 0r any other value.

Edited after the comment:

If it doesn't not work then add width to touchableopacity also

Comment: Thanks Piyush, for your response. Changing the image width does not seem to work. I've tried width: '100%' and any other value 100, 200, 300, etc.

Comment: Try adding some width to touchable Opacity. It seems the parent of touchable Opacity is having flex as 1 and flex direction as coloumn.

Comment: Still nothing. added with in various amounts like before with 100% and 100, 200, 800. Still not showing anything for the image, even with changing both widths for TouchableOpacity and the Image tags :(

Comment: So, I got it to work in a roundabout weird way. I've used the <ImageBackground> Element instead of the <Image> Element and somehow the image started showing... baffled and trying to understand why but no complaints from me. I'll read up on it more and try to make it work with <Image>. Thanks!