# How to make image inside TouchableOpacity button overflow button in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native

So imagine we want to have an image inside a TouchableOpacity button.

The image is slightly taller then the button and we want it to overflow. Currently the image gets clipped just before the top. I am debugging on Android.

How can I get an image to overflow a button in react native?

[image]

Comment: read this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712920/image-inside-touchableopacity-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute position with image :

```js
<TouchableOpacity>
  <Text></Text>
  <Image style={{position:'absolute', width:.., height:.., left:.., top:..}}/>

</TouchableOpacity>
```